# Applying validation to angular2 form using angular-form-validator gives error on the console

Tags: angular, validation, angular2-template, angular2-forms

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined
    at Object.a.6../controller/ngFormValidatorCtrl (eval at webpackJsonp.../../../../script-loader/addScript.js.module.exports (addScript.js:9), <anonymous>:1:10372)
    at s (eval at webpackJsonp.../../../../script-loader/addScript.js.module.exports (addScript.js:9), <anonymous>:1:254)
    at r (eval at webpackJsonp.../../../../script-loader/addScript.js.module.exports (addScript.js:9), <anonymous>:1:421)
    at eval (eval at webpackJsonp.../../../../script-loader/addScript.js.module.exports (addScript.js:9), <anonymous>:1:438)
    at eval (<anonymous>)
    at webpackJsonp.../../../../script-loader/addScript.js.module.exports (addScript.js:9)
    at Object.../../../../script-loader/index.js!../../../../angular-form-validator/dist/js/ngFormValidator.min.js (ngFormValidator.min.js?c268:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap e0780ad229468d3f0586:54)
    at Object.2 (scripts.bundle.js:66)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap e0780ad229468d3f0586:54)
a.6../controller/ngFormValidatorCtrl @ VM11782:1
s @ VM11782:1
r @ VM11782:1
(anonymous) @ VM11782:1
webpackJsonp.../../../../script-loader/addScript.js.module.exports @ addScript.js:9
../../../../script-loader/index.js!../../../../angular-form-validator/dist/js/ngFormValidator.min.js @ ngFormValidator.min.js?c268:1
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap e0780ad229468d3f0586:54
2 @ scripts.bundle.js:66
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap e0780ad229468d3f0586:54
webpackJsonpCallback @ bootstrap e0780ad229468d3f0586:25
(anonymous) @ scripts.bundle.js:1
```

I am using this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-form-validator with angular2. Although validation using Custom validator is an option like here: https://angular.io/guide/form-validation. But, I wanted to keep the validation in HTML file as much as possible. The code is running fine but with errors on the console. Can anyone suggest to remove this error trace?

Comment: can you make a plunker or a html/.ts snippet

Comment: can you add custom validation implemented componet snippet